# Unidirectional JPA

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have a database (JPA 2 Eclipselink) where there is Order and Item, each order can have many items and each item can be assigned only to one order. This is unidirectional relation.

**The Order Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

**The Item entity has:**

```
@Entity
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    Order o;
}
```

But how to setup that if an order is deleted from the database all Items having reference to it would be deleted? Is it possible in unidirectional relationship, or I have to create bidirectional and put @OneToMany(cascade=remove) in the Order Entity Class? or keep it unidirectional but the owning side would be Order and remove any reference to order from item Entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you make the association bidirectional and add a cascade, as you suggest yourself in your question, or you explicitely delete all the items linked to the order (using a JPQL delete query, or by searching them and then deleting them), and then delete the order.

A bidirectional association makes sense in this case, and you'll probably benefit from it in several other places in your code.

Comment: Thank you, 
If I use bidirectional relationship do I have to use @JoinColumn or can I just add mappedBy in the other side of owning part of the relation. And if I declare @Column(name="ORDER_ID") on id field the mappedby should by mappedby="ORDER_ID" not (..)="id" yes? I don't really understand the JoinColumn

Comment: You MUST use `mappedBy="order"` on Order.items, and leave it as it is on Item.order. `mappedBy="order"` says: go see the field "order" in the other side of the association (i.e. in Item) to see how this bidirectional association is mapped.

Comment: that is very nicely described thank you! May I ask you what @JoinColumn does then? Thanks again

Comment: JoinColumn allows telling that the association is mapped using a join column. This is the default though for a ManyToOne association. So you would use it in order to customize the name of the column used to hold the foreign key to the order table. Just like Column, if you don't use it, it uses a default name. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html